# cin causing cout to flush, after I untied the two streams

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to understand the behavior of iostreams with respect to tie(). From what I find, the below code should NOT output anything to the screen.

```
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int i;
    cout << "TEST";
    cin >> i;
    while (true);
```

Instead it should behave like

```
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int i;
    cout << "TEST";
    read(0, &i, sizeof(int));
    while (true);
```

In other words, cout buffer is getting flushed when cin input is invoked, even though the streams are untied. I have tried compiling this code with g++ 4.8.0 and 4.6.3. 
I have also tried calling `cin.tie()` after `cin.tie(NULL)` which correctly returns NULL, so the streams should not be tied.

Is there more to tie() that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't execute `cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`, so your `std::cout` is *synchronized* with C I/O, which means that every single output is individually and immediately sent over to a C I/O library call, and is then subject to the implementation-defined rules of glibc, in your case.

On a quick check, [this glibc manual](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_12.html) mentions that

> ...buffered output on a stream is flushed automatically:
>
> - Whenever an input operation on any stream actually reads data from its file.

(although it doesn't sound convincing since nothing was read from stdin yet.. in any case, `cout.sync_with_stdio(false)` makes this `cin.tie(NULL)` testcase behave as expected on my Linux).